# How to get all tasks resolved by a user in jira 5.2

Tags: jira, jql

I want to know all the tasks that were "resolved" by user in jira within a range of dates. we are on 5.2 version of Jira.

Note: Their current status could by any.

Answer (score 3):

Using issue navigator (and replacing project1 and user1 with your project name and user name respectively):

> project = project1 and status WAS "Resolved" BY user1 DURING ("2010/01/01","2011/01/01")